# How to get the previous value in (input) event in angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to add the value and also need to remove the previous value by comparing with a new value.

```
 var  total = [];
 onSearchChange(event) {
    total.push(event);
    var sumNumber = total.reduce(
      (acc, cur) => acc + Number(cur),
      0
    );
    console.log("get all the changed value, I need to remove the previous values in the total list");
  }
```

```html
 <input type='number' (input)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)" />
```

Comment: How do you compare them ?

Comment: you can assign a model to this `input` field. That will be the old value

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufd15s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if the event itself retains the previous value. You can create a component property to hold the previous value and set it in every `input` event.

```
<input id="inputId" type="number" value=23 (input)="foo($event.target.value)">
// have some default value only if you want

previousValue: number

foo(value) {
    console.log("previous value ", this.previousValue);
    console.log("new value ", value);
    this.previousValue = value
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.previousValue = parseInt((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('inputId')).value)
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufd15s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

You can also add a helper event listener `keydown` (which seems unnecessary but just saying) on the `input` element. `keydown` will occur before `input` so with keydown you can grab the previous value. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sjxvgp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts